# Switch combobox source based on radio button using PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, combobox

I have a couple of comboboxes that use an XML file for a data source. I would like to be able to switch the loaded XML file using jQuery based on the selection made in a radio button selection, but I'm not sure where to get started.

In the form header I have:

```
<?php $items = simplexml_load_file("items.xml"); ?>
```

Then in the form itself I'm loading the contents like this:

```
  <select class="input_meas_mat form-control" name="mat" id="meas_mat">
    <?php foreach($items->children() as $product){ ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $product; ?>"><?php echo $product; ?></option> 
    <?php }?> 
  </select>
```

Will I need to completely change the way I'm loading the combobox?

Comment: If you want to switch the xml file without reloading the page, you must change the way combobox loaded.